# Joining two tables based on column regular expression matching

Tags: sql, regex, ansi-sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

**AIM**: To join two tables contingent on one column from one table containing a word mentioned in another column from another table.

**TABLE 1**:

```html
tibble::tribble(
  ~ORDER_ID,                                                         ~SUPERNAME_WITH_MODS, ~QUANTITY,
          1,                           "Mods, , 2 Regular Fries, 2 Regular Fries (Mods),",         0,
          2,     "Tomatoes, Tomatoes (Toppings), Toppings, , Lettuce, Lettuce (Toppings)",         0,
          3, "Chicken, Dirty Chicken Cheeseburger, Dirty Chicken Cheeseburger (Chicken),",         0,
          4,  "Garlic & Buttermilk Mayo Dip Pot, Garlic & Buttermilk Mayo Dip Pot (Dips)",         0,
          5,                            "Garlic Bread Pizza, , Verdure, Verdure (Pizza),",         0,
          6,   "Skinny Fries (Salt) - Large, Skinny Fries (Salt) - Large (Add On Sides),",         0,
          7,                    "CYOSalad Veg, , Green Beans, Green Beans (CYOSalad Veg)",         0,
          8,                     "Little Five Guys Style, Little Five Guys Style (Fries)",         0,
          9,                          "Chicken de Volaille (Mains), Chips, Chips (Sides)",         0,
         10,                                     "Modifiers, Medium, Medium (Modifiers),",         0
  )
```

**TABLE 2:**

```html
tibble::tribble(
  ~ingredient, ~contributor,
       "beef",       "beef",
      "chili",       "beef",
     "chilli",       "beef",
       "pork",       "pork",
      "bacon",       "pork",
    "chicken",    "chicken"
  )
```

**Expected result**:

Joining table 1 and 2 based on the column `SUPERNAME_WITH_MODS` from table 1, containing any word in the `ingredient` column from table 2. Note it returns `NULL` when there is no match.

I would also like to emphasise it has to match the entire word in any casing (upper or lower).

```html
tibble::tribble(
  ~ORDER_ID,                                                         ~SUPERNAME_WITH_MODS, ~QUANTITY, ~ingredient, ~contributor,
          1,                           "Mods, , 2 Regular Fries, 2 Regular Fries (Mods),",         0,      "NULL",       "NULL",
          2,     "Tomatoes, Tomatoes (Toppings), Toppings, , Lettuce, Lettuce (Toppings)",         0,      "NULL",       "NULL",
          3, "Chicken, Dirty Chicken Cheeseburger, Dirty Chicken Cheeseburger (Chicken),",         0,   "chicken",    "chicken",
          4,  "Garlic & Buttermilk Mayo Dip Pot, Garlic & Buttermilk Mayo Dip Pot (Dips)",         0,      "NULL",       "NULL",
          5,                            "Garlic Bread Pizza, , Verdure, Verdure (Pizza),",         0,      "NULL",       "NULL",
          6,   "Skinny Fries (Salt) - Large, Skinny Fries (Salt) - Large (Add On Sides),",         0,      "NULL",       "NULL",
          7,                    "CYOSalad Veg, , Green Beans, Green Beans (CYOSalad Veg)",         0,      "NULL",       "NULL",
          8,                     "Little Five Guys Style, Little Five Guys Style (Fries)",         0,      "NULL",       "NULL",
          9,                          "Chicken de Volaille (Mains), Chips, Chips (Sides)",         0,      "NULL",       "NULL",
         10,                                     "Modifiers, Medium, Medium (Modifiers),",         0,      "NULL",       "NULL"
  )
```

**PROBLEM** I know this will be left join but I'm not sure what I should write in the `ON` part of the join.

Comment: If somebody gives me a -1,  please say why so I can improve the question.

Comment: Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you want to handle the case where there are multiple matches. You might like to add a `GROUP BY` clause if desired.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON CONTAINS(LOWER(t1.supername_with_mods), LOWER(t2.ingredient));
```